# How to work with the result of the wild sympy

Tags: wildcard, sympy

I have the following code:

```
f=tan(x)*x**2
q=Wild('q')
s=f.match(tan(q))
s={q_ : x}
```

How to work with the result of the "wild"? How to not address the array, for example, s[0], s{0}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wild` can be used when you have an expression which is the result of some complicated calculation, but you know it has to be of the form `sin(something)` times `something else`. Then `s[q]` will be the sympy expression for the "something". And `s[p]` for the "something else". This could be used to investigate both p and q. Or to further work with a simplified version of f, substituting p and q with new variables, especially if p and q would be complex expressions involving multiple variables.

Many more use cases are possible.

Here is an example:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, y, z

p = Wild('p')
q = Wild('q')
f = tan(x) * x**2
s = f.match(p*tan(q))
print(f'f is the tangent of "{s[q]}" multiplied by "{s[p]}"')
g = f.xreplace({s[q]: y, s[p]:z})
print(f'f rewritten in simplified form as a function of y and z: "{g}"')
h = s[p] * s[q]
print(f'a new function h, combining parts of f: "{h}"')
```

Output:

```
f is the tangent of "x" multiplied by "x**2"
f rewritten in simplified form as a function of y and z: "z*tan(y)"
a new function h, combining parts of f: "x**3"
```

If you're interested in all arguments from `tan` that appear in `f` written as a product, you might try:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x

f = tan(x+2)*tan(x*x+1)*7*(x+1)*tan(1/x)

if f.func == Mul:
    all_tan_args = [a.args[0] for a in f.args if a.func == tan]
    # note: the [0] is needed because args give a tupple of arguments and
    #   in the case of tan you'ld want the first (there is only one)
elif f.func == tan:
    all_tan_args = [f.args[0]]
else:
    all_tan_args = []

prod = 1
for a in all_tan_args:
    prod *= a

print(f'All the tangent arguments are: {all_tan_args}')
print(f'Their product is: {prod}')
```

Output:

```
All the tangent arguments are: [1/x, x**2 + 1, x + 2]
Their product is: (x + 2)*(x**2 + 1)/x
```

Note that neither method would work for `f = tan(x)**2`. For that, you'ld need to write another `match` and decide whether you'ld want to take the same power of the arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but I need, for example: s{p}*s{q}, e.t.c, to pull out the argument of tan and work with him further

Comment: Thanks, it really works! However, for f=tan(x-2)*x**2*tan(x) it doesn’t work anymore.... Although it can be done in a loop. Thanks!

Comment: For `f=tan(x-2)*x**2*tan(x)` you'ld need an extra `Wild` (or repeat the process). Note that `match` wants to match the complete expression against your wildcards. To use it, you need a quite exact idea about the structure of `f`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Tell me how to leave a review. Could not find